# cant boot after update

Tags: boot, drivers, updates, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xorg server configuration fail - no screens detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167000/xorg-server-configuration-fail-no-screens-detected)

After update (28. september) my pc freezes  and than restart after few secs. I have installed ubuntu 12.04 x64. I tried to boot into failsafe mod, but same thing happens. I can access terminal. Here is error log.
x.org x server 1.11.3, release date 2011-12-16

```
[30.875] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.sp
[30.875] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
[30.875] (ww) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[30.875] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[30.875] (II) unloading vesa
[30.875] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[30.875]
Fatal server error:
[30.875] no screens found
[30.875]
Please consult the X.org support
       At wiki.x.org
[30.875] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log" for additional information.
[30.875]
[30.877] ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[30.877] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file
```

I cant post whole file, its too long...there is no any errors before those lines.
I think its problem with drivers, but i dont know how to fix it.
Please help!

```
AMD phenom x4 840
6GB ddr3
Radeon HD 5570, official AMD drivers
```