# Boot problem in Ubuntu

Tags: boot

Yesterday night I directly shutdown my computer by pressing the shutdown key from the keyboard. This morning when I started my computer, a purple screen appears, then Ubuntu  logo loads but it doesn't go to the login screen, instead a black screen with a cursor on upper left screen appears, and then nothing happens. I am new to Ubuntu. Please help me fix this problem without having to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Try pressing the `Shift` key right after the BIOS screen, do you get the recovery menu?

Comment: Yes .i got it but dont know what to do next

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to the recovery menu choose

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes i tried that. But what to do with root

Comment: Nothing, try clean, and dpkg.

Comment: I did those tooo. Now what should i do? Should i reboot?

Comment: I dont know what to do. Evryy times ubuntu loads up to the part where it asks ur usernameand password but then dark screen comes. By pressing shift key and  failsafex mode i am able to go to my terminal  and can use the tetminal normally but then i cant see my desktop

Comment: What happens when you type `sudo startx` in terminal?

Comment: At the end it says : fetal server error. No screens found. Plz consult The X.Org foundation support for help. Also check log file at:/var/log/xorg.o.log for additional information

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167000/xorg-server-configuration-fail-no-screens-detected).

Comment: How to instsll xserver.xorg