# Cant access ubuntu GUI from XEN

Tags: gui, desktop-environments, xen

I have ubuntu server installed on my XEN server. Now due to some reasons i need to configure some GUI based application on Ubuntu so for that i installed ubuntu-desktop via apt-get. Now when i want use startx, it gives me below error. i am using Xen Center's console.

```
 Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 14 14:10:44 2014
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
xinit: server error
```

Xord log file,

```
[  2736.360] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2736.360]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[  2736.360]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2736.360]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  2736.360] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2736.360] (II) Unloading vesa
[  2736.360] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 32587)
[  2736.360] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2736.361] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2736.361] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2736.361]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[  2736.361]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  2736.361] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2736.361] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  2736.361] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 32587)
[  2736.361] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2736.361] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2736.361] (++) using VT number 8

[  2736.361] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[  2736.361] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  2736.361] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2736.361] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2736.361] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2736.362] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2736.362] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2736.362]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  2736.362]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[  2736.362] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  2736.362] (EE) No devices detected.
[  2736.362]
Fatal server error:
[  2736.362] no screens found
```

Comment: Have you seen this => [Xorg server configuration fail - no screens detected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167000/xorg-server-configuration-fail-no-screens-detected)

Comment: yes but couldn't find any clue (or may be its me). please check it in my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some graphics cards (in particular, or other hardware in general) that requires propriety modules/drivers? This is most common cause of console display / no graphics in Xen domains. No *device detection* also indicates that proper modules for hardware are missing.