# "Screens not found" error when editing xorg.conf upon reboot

Tags: boot, xorg, display, display-resolution, xorg.conf

This is my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier   "Screen0"
    Device       "Device0"
    Monitor      "Montior0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    Subsection   "Display"
        Depth      24
        Modes      "1024 x 768" "1280 x 960" "1366 x 768" "1280 x 1024" "1440 x 900" "1440 x 960" "1440 x 1080" "1600 x 1200" "1920 x 1080" "1920 x 1200"
    EndSubsection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    VendorName  "Monitor0"
    ModelName   "Model0"
    HorizSync   30 - 300
    VertRefresh 30 - 500
EndSection

        Modeline "1440x1080_60.00"  129.00  1440 1528 1680 1920  1080 1083 1087 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

When I reboot my PC, I find that I'm unable to get a graphical login.
The error I get is along the lines of:

```
Error in xorg.conf
This section must have an Identifier line.
EE problem/error parsing the config line
Fatal server error: no screens found
```

What's the reason for this and how can solve it?
All questions on this have no solutions...

Output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    34.304] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    34.304] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    34.304] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    34.304] Current Operating System: Linux pointcarre-OptiPlex-755 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    34.304] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=94e3a36a-e676-4f71-b4fd-1edcc90700da ro quiet splash
[    34.304] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[    34.304] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    34.304] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    34.304]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    34.304] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    34.304] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Nov 13 21:00:30 2015
[    34.390] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    34.427] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    34.427] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    34.427] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    34.427] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    34.427] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    34.427] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    34.427] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    34.427] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    34.427] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    34.427]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.427] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.427]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.427] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.427]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.427] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    34.427]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.427] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    34.427]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.428] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    34.428] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    34.428] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    34.428] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f4070706d40
[    34.428] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    34.428]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    34.428]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    34.428]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    34.428]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    34.428] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    34.429] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0a65:1043:848f rev 162, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    34.429] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    34.430] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    34.430] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    34.430] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    34.430] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    34.430] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    34.430] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    34.456] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    34.456]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.456]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    34.456] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.93  Wed Aug 19 16:23:51 PDT 2015
[    34.456] Loading extension GLX
[    34.456] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    34.456] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    34.456] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[    34.456] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[    34.456] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    34.456] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    34.456] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    34.456] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    34.456] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    34.456] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    34.457] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    34.457]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.457]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.457] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    34.457] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    34.472] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.472]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.10
[    34.472]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    34.473] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    34.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    34.473] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.473]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    34.473]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    34.473] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    34.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    34.473] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.473]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    34.473]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    34.473] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    34.474] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    34.474] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.474]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    34.474]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.474]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    34.474] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  340.93  Wed Aug 19 16:01:53 PDT 2015
[    34.474] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    34.474] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Nov 7 14:56:48 2013 +1000
[    34.474] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    34.474]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    34.474]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    34.474]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    34.474]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    34.474]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    34.474]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    34.474]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    34.474]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    34.474]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    34.474]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    34.474]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    34.474]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    34.474]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    34.474] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    34.474] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    34.474] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    34.474] (++) using VT number 8

[    34.477] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    34.477] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    34.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    34.532] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.532]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.532]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.532] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[    34.532] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    34.532] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    34.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    34.533] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.533]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.533]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.533] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    34.533] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    34.533] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    34.533] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    34.534] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    34.534] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    34.534] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    34.534] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    34.534] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.534]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    34.534]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    34.534] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    34.534] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    34.534] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    34.534] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    34.534] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    34.534] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    34.534] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    34.534] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    35.126] (II) NVIDIA(0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    35.126] (II) NVIDIA(0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    35.126] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20150116)
[    35.127] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 210 (GT218) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    35.127] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    35.127] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.18.64.00.05
[    35.127] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 210 at PCI:1:0:0
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0) (boot, connected)
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    35.129] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    35.129] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    35.129] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0) (Using EDID frequencies
[    35.129] (**) NVIDIA(0):     has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    35.132] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    35.132] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.132] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    35.132] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    35.132] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    35.132] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.132] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1280 x 1024
[    35.156] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (95, 96); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    35.156] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    35.156] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.156] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    35.156] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.156] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    35.156] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.157] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    35.157] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.157] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    35.157] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.157] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.157] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    35.157] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    35.161] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    35.212] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    35.237] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    35.237] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    35.237] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    35.237] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    35.237] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    35.238] Loading extension XINERAMA
[    35.238] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    35.238] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    35.238] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    35.238] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    35.238] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    35.238] (--) RandR disabled
[    35.244] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    35.245] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    35.261] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    35.265] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    35.265] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.265] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    35.265] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    35.285] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.285]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
[    35.285]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    35.285]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[    35.285] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    35.285] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    35.285] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    35.285] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    35.285] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    35.285] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.285] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    35.285] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    35.285] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.285] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.285] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    35.287] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2B4266AA55228AE7D9557A18F1965DBA19850816.xkm
[    35.288] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    35.288] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.288] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    35.288] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    35.288] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    35.288] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    35.288] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    35.288] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.288] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    35.288] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    35.288] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.288] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.288] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    35.288] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0) card0 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0
[    35.288] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    35.289] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
[    35.289] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.289] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.289] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[    35.289] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.289] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event10)
[    35.290] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.290] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event9)
[    35.290] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.290] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out (/dev/input/event6)
[    35.290] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.290] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.291] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event5)
[    35.291] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.291] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.291] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    35.291] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.291] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.291] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event7)
[    35.291] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.291] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.292] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/event2)
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    35.292] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE'
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: always reports core events
[    35.292] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    35.292] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2516
[    35.292] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    35.292] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    35.292] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found relative axes
[    35.292] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found x and y relative axes
[    35.292] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Configuring as mouse
[    35.292] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Adding scrollwheel support
[    35.292] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    35.292] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    35.292] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input5/event2"
[    35.292] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB OPTICAL MOUSE" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    35.292] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: initialized for relative axes.
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    35.292] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    35.293] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    35.293] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.293] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.293] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Chicony USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    35.293] (**) Chicony USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.293] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Chicony USB Keyboard'
[    35.293] (**) Chicony USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[    35.293] (**) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    35.293] (--) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0x402
[    35.293] (--) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Found keys
[    35.293] (II) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.293] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.0/input/input6/event3"
[    35.293] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Chicony USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    35.293] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.293] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.293] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    35.294] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Chicony USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    35.294] (**) Chicony USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.294] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Chicony USB Keyboard'
[    35.294] (**) Chicony USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[    35.294] (**) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    35.294] (--) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0x402
[    35.294] (--) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Found keys
[    35.294] (II) evdev: Chicony USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.294] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.1/input/input7/event4"
[    35.294] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Chicony USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    35.294] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.294] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.294] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   111.577] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   111.577] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   117.074] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   117.074] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   117.811] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   117.811] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   118.912] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7996F6726817F73651B9DE0FDA11E35FC4524568.xkm
[   119.477] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   139.935] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   139.935] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   150.687] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   150.691] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   150.695] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   150.698] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   150.702] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
[   150.706] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F4830027FD6DFAF7D5CB4AF430AE062CB8989800.xkm
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: @kos updated answer

Comment: I will not mark as duplicate, because between 12.04 and your version (I'm going to guess you aren't using 12.04) there may be changes in Xorg, however I would recommend attempting what is described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167000/xorg-server-configuration-fail-no-screens-detected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says. One of your sections (in the xorg.conf file) does not have an Identifier line.

The `Section "Monitor"` section has VendorName, ModelName, HorizSync and VertRefresh lines but no Identifier.

Add the following line directly after `Section "Monitor"` and before VendorName:
`Identifier   "Monitor0"`

Your `Section "Screen"` references a Monitor `"Montior0"` (sic). Therefore it needs to find a Monitor with the Identifier `"Montior0"` (sic). It also highlights a possible typo there too.

Therefore, change `"Montior0"` to `"Monitor0"` in the `Section "Screen"` and add the `Identifier "Monitor0"` line in the `Section "Monitor"`. Hopefully that should do it.

In case you (or future readers of this post) don't know how: Edit the xorg.conf file with the following command:
`sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment into a more accessible answer, there are 2 steps to attempt to fix this.

1. Move (Delete) ~/.config/monitors.xml
   Step 1: Since we cannot use a GUI (Graphical User Interface) we will have to boot into Grub.
   Step 2: Once in Grub, enable networking, then drop to shell prompt.
   Step 3: Once in Grub do `mv ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/old_monitors.xml`
   Step 4: Move on to the second step we will need to do (Re-installing xorg)
   <>
2. Re-install Xorg
   Pre-steps: Repeat steps 1 & 2 from above, to get to shell.
   Step 1: Do `apt-get purge xauth`
   Step 2: Do `apt-get autoremove`
   Step 3: Do `apt-get install xauth`
   Step 4: Do `reboot now`

Done! Enjoy your new working Xorg installation!